# Head at master but still detached?

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout, git-reset

Say I have a Git repo with three commits:

```
$ git log --oneline
62fa462 (HEAD, master) Third commit
76f2df9 Second commit
c05b82a First commit
```

Now I accidentally use `checkout` to move `HEAD` to the second commit:

```
$ git checkout 76f2df9
Previous HEAD position was 62fa462 Third commit
HEAD is now at 76f2df9 Second commit
```

I then want to restore the previous state so I use `reset`:

```
$ git reset --hard 62fa462
HEAD is now at 62fa462 Third commit
```

That worked, and as can be seen in the log, `HEAD` is again pointing to `master`:

```
$ git log --oneline
62fa462 (HEAD, master) Third commit
76f2df9 Second commit
c05b82a First commit
```

However, when I check the status, I get:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from 76f2df9
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I don't really get this, why is `HEAD` still detached? In the log, it shows `(HEAD, master)` so it should point to the `master` branch, right? At least the log looks exactly like at the beginning when everything was fine.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A detached HEAD means that `HEAD` is not a link to a branch head. A branch head is always a reference to a commit. `HEAD`, on the other hand, is a reference to either a commit or a branch head.

When you start, `HEAD` is specifically a reference to `master`, *not* `62fa462`; graphically, it looks like

```
62fa462 <----- master <---- HEAD
   |
   v
76f2df9
   |
   v
c05b82a
```

After your checkout, `HEAD` no longer references a branch head, but a commit directly; *that's* what is meant by being detached.

```
$ git checkout 76f2df9


62fa462 <-+-- master
   |
   v
76f2df9 <----- HEAD
   |
   v
c05b82a
```

When you ran `reset`, you didn't check out the branch `master`; you checked out the commit that `master` referenced:

```
62fa462 <-+-- master
   |       \-- HEAD
   v
76f2df9
   |
   v
c05b82a
```

Only when you have a *branch* checked out can a branch head be advanced by a new commit; otherwise, only `HEAD` references the new commit, and you'll lose track of it the next time you run `git checkout`.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot sense.